# What are the implications of the fact that the determinant of this general matrix is 4?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Suppose we have the following matrix $A\in M(4\times 4;\;\mathbb{R})$ with $\det(A) =4$ :
$$A=
\begin{pmatrix}
a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} & a_{14}\\
a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} & a_{24}\\
a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33} & a_{34}\\
a_{41} & a_{42} & a_{43} & a_{44}
\end{pmatrix}
$$

> What are the implications of the fact that the determinant of this general matrix is 4 or in other words, what are the characteristics/properties that follow from that fact?

### EDIT:

How does this help me if *(for example)* I want to compute the determinant of  \begin{pmatrix} 2a_{31}+a_{21} & 2a_{32}+a_{22} & 2a_{33}+a_{23} & 2a_{34}+a_{24} \\ a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} & a_{24}\\ 3a_{11} & 3a_{12} & 3a_{13} & 3a_{14}\\ a_{41} & a_{42} & a_{43} & a_{44} \end{pmatrix}?

Comment: It is non-singular and the product of its eigen values is $4$.

Comment: How does this help me if  for example I want to compute the determinant of  \begin{pmatrix} 2a_{31}+a_{21} & 2a_{32}+a_{22} & 2a_{33}+a_{23} & 2a_{34}+a_{24} \\ a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} & a_{24}\\ 3a_{11} & 3a_{12} & 3a_{13} & 3a_{14}\\ a_{41} & a_{42} & a_{43} & a_{44} \end{pmatrix}?

Comment: Can you explain a little further how you came to that solution? Is it because we exchanged two rows and mutiplied by 3? Shouldn't it be $-\frac{1}{3}\cdot 4$ then?

Comment: @Doesbaddel sorry,  the determinant is $3*2*(-1)*4$, if you do some elementary transformations you can get to matrix A and using properties of determinants that should be what you get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\begin{vmatrix} 2a_{31}+a_{21} & 2a_{32}+a_{22} & 2a_{33}+a_{23} & 2a_{34}+a_{24} \\ a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} & a_{24}\\ 3a_{11} & 3a_{12} & 3a_{13} & 3a_{14}\\ a_{41} & a_{42} & a_{43} & a_{44} \end{vmatrix}
=\\
\begin{vmatrix} 2a_{31} & 2a_{32} & 2a_{33} & 2a_{34} \\ a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} & a_{24}\\ 3a_{11} & 3a_{12} & 3a_{13} & 3a_{14}\\ a_{41} & a_{42} & a_{43} & a_{44} \end{vmatrix}
=
2 \cdot 3
\begin{vmatrix} a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33} & a_{34} \\ a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} & a_{24}\\ a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} & a_{14}\\ a_{41} & a_{42} & a_{43} & a_{44} \end{vmatrix}
=
-2 \cdot 3
\begin{vmatrix} a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} & a_{14} \\ a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} & a_{24}\\ a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33} & a_{34} \\ a_{41} & a_{42} & a_{43} & a_{44} \end{vmatrix}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $ A\in M(n\times n;\;\mathbb{R})$ invertible and let $a_1,...,a_n$ be the columns of $A$.

Put $B=( \frac{4}{\det(A)}a_1,a_2,..,a_n)$, then we have $\det(B)=4.$